# A tales and stories children book suitable for adult learners?

Tags: learning, culture

I like to read children literature in foreign languages I am learning. I usually do not have troubles picking them in european language, but I would need recommendation for Japanese.

I would like a book

- with a small vocabulary (and eventually a glossary)
- explaining tales of ancient Japan or little zen stories or a few proverbs.
- easy to read aloud (with an audio CD would be perfect)
- a series of self-contained short stories instead of a longer one.

Comment: Awesome question! +1 despite likely being considered off-topic by some, because I think this is very useful information -- and I can sympathize, as I've had trouble answering this same question myself in the past.

Comment: topicness aside, it is not really a question (in that there is no single objective answer)... But does make a good Community Wiki! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Check out some [graded readers](http://www.thejapanshop.com/Readers-and-More-Japanese-Bookstore-Products/b/2359251011?ie=UTF8&title=Readers%20and%20More).  They're perfect for everything you've asked for, and sorted by reading ability so you can some that are perfect.